# Responsive image in height and width within a <figure>

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a `<figure>`. I want when the window is resized, the image has responsive behavior, I want to always be able to observe `100%` of the height and width of the image. I want the whole image to always be seen.

http://jsfiddle.net/ckdm0joj/

```css
figure.figure_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.figure_container img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure class='figure_container'>
  <img src='https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/dory_characters_0afa6e45.jpeg?region=0%2C0%2C1200%2C778' />
</figure>
```

Comment: is this what you try to do ? http://jsfiddle.net/ckdm0joj/1/  max-height:250px on figure will not let image be 100% width without stretching it or overflow it

Comment: @GCyrillus thanks but, I want the width of the image to be 100%, as well as in the container, and the height is 100% of the container.

Comment: Do you also want to maintain the image aspect ratio?

Comment: @Pangloss what do you think? I'm not sure, it's for a web page, would it be good?

Comment: I don't know but I'd say yes, so you want the figure to adjust the height so that the whole image to be always seen?

Comment: @Pangloss I want the image to adapt 100% to the size of the figure, both in height and width.

Comment: That would be possible only if stretch the image, or allow it to cut off, otherwise it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

Replace following `CSS` with this:

```
.figure_container img{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: inherit;
  width: auto;
}
```

By adding `inherit` to the `max-height` property, you are excerly telling `CSS` not to make the image heigher than its parent element. So if you changes the `.figure-container` height to `350px` the `max-height` of the image will also be `350px`

> The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value
>   from its parent element.

**EDIT AFTER READING YOUR COMMENTS:**

If you want your full `width` of its container replace `width: auto` with `width: 100%`. However, this will stretch your image, because the `.figure-container`has a `max-width` of `250px`

```
.figure_container img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: inherit;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
figure.figure_container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 250px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.figure_container img{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure class='figure_container'>
  <img src='https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/dory_characters_0afa6e45.jpeg?region=0%2C0%2C1200%2C778' />
</figure>
```

Comment: Great, but I need the image to fit 100% of the width of the figure, which in this case is 100%

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind to see your image being stretch , flex can be the way : http://jsfiddle.net/ckdm0joj/2/

```css
figure {
  display:flex;
  max-height:250px;
  border-radius:6px;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}
img {
  flex:1;
}
body {
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<figure class='figure_container'>
  <img src='https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/dory_characters_0afa6e45.jpeg?region=0%2C0%2C1200%2C778' />
</figure>
```

Comment: Thanks, I value your effort, but in this case the image is not completely seen (width)

Comment: ?? how come it is not entirely seen ? it is the only content here .... exept for the radius corners. you can even set a margin to it  http://jsfiddle.net/ckdm0joj/3/ what do you think is missing here ?